# How to get incoming mail using java and google gmail-api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gmail-api, email, google-api-java-client

I want to integrate Gmail in Spring boot project. My requirement is,

1. get user gmail access using google auth
2. send email
3. save all new incoming email of all integrated account
4. filter email with the specific email/domain
5. Display all emails

I followed this doc [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

Using this I am able to access user gmail account and send email, but couldn't find anything about how to recieve incoimng mail, filter and process data using gmail-api or any other library.

Can any one please help me about how to listen for user new incoming email and filter them?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

First of all, in order to process your incoming emails, make use of [Filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings). By doing so you can label all your emails "before they hit your inbox" as let's say **process** label and remove the **INBOX** label which is by default all your emails label, take a look into this [JAVA Example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings#examples). Once you've done this simply [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) all your emails labeled as **process** using its **labelID**.

Second, use [Gmail Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) and treat all emails labeled as **process**.

Keep in mind that using Pub/Sub requires some extra steps mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#prerequisites).

### References

- [Managing Filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings)
- [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)
- [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview)